# How should I implement reCaptcha v3 if my front and backend live on different domains?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have several websites (SPAs), each one running on it's own domain. All these SPAs use the same API, which is hosted on another domain.

I'd like to implement reCaptcha v3 on my SPAs, but I'm not really sure how exactly the entire validation process would work.

Who would be in charge of receiving the callback from Google's service? If the backend, how does the frontend validate itself to the backend?

The SPAs are made with Vue and the backend is a Django app with Django Rest Framework. The backend is stateless, so there are no cookies.